# java How do I print a reversed AND every other element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

*This is my first question, so sorry if I'm not clear*

So I'm trying to write a void function printReverse that prints a reversed array and skips every other element in the process. This is what I have:

```
void printReverse(int[] array) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i+=2){
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length - i - 1];
        array[array.length - i - 1] = temp;
        while(i < array.length){
            println(array[i]);   
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Say that I had an array of {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}, I'm trying to print out on different lines (println) 
60 
40 
20

How would I do that with the code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also start from the end of the array, it really easy to do this like that:

```
for(int i=array.length-1; i>=0; i=i-2)
    System.out.println(array[i]);
```

notice that `i=array.length-1` as if `array.length` is 3 for example, the last index will be 2. Also notice that `i>=0` as `i` is initialize to the end of the array and 0 is the first index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int count = 0;
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (count++ % 2 != 0) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides having the system just print it, you could use a for loop to do this.

So,

```
for (int i = 6, i > array.length, i - 2)
{
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Which would print out every other element in reverse order, given that there are 6 elements in the array. Of course, you could have a variable set to the length of the array, and plug in the variable instead of six, but this is just an example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this example is bad, as `i=6` is just one specific case, `i>array.length` will make the loop to run forever/not run at all and `i-2` is wrong syntax, `i=i-2` is correct.

Comment: Also, this example won't work as the for loop has commas to separate the statements, not semicolons

Answer (score 0):

[Check Image for Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVTE4.png) **Here you go in simple way,Thank you!!**

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class Demo
    {  
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter total number of elemets: ");
            int total = sc.nextInt();
            int[]arr1 = new int[total];
            int[]arr2 = new int[total];

            System.out.print("Enter elemets: ");

            for(int i = 0; i<total; i++)
            {
                arr1[i]= sc.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.print("Original Array: " +Arrays.toString(arr1));
            System.out.println();

            for(int a = 0 ; a< total; a++)
            {
                for(int j =total-a-1; j>=0; j--)
                {               
                        arr2[a]= arr1[j];
                        break;              
                }

            }
            System.out.print("Reversed Array: " +Arrays.toString(arr2));
        }    
    }
```

Comment: I have attached it, you can directly complie and run it on http://www.browxy.com :)